# Rails map_with_index?

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
    :participants => item.item_participations.map { |item|
      {:item_image => item.user.profile_pic.url(:small)}
    }
```

I want this to happen no more than 3 times inside. I tried map_with_index but that did not work.

Any suggestions on how I can break after a max of 3 runs in the loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
my_array.take(3).map { |element| calculate_something_from(element) }
```

Comment: Where is the `take` method defined?

Comment: The take method is defined in Enumerable -> http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Enumerable.html#M003070

Answer (score 29):

As of Ruby 1.9, you can use map.with_index:

```
:participants => item.item_participations.map.with_index { |item, idx|
  {:item_image => item.user.profile_pic.url(:small)}
  break if i == 2  
}
```

Although I kind of prefer the method proposed by Justice.

Comment: This isn't working for me.. Throws an error: `undefined method 'with_index' for #<Array:0x102f70320>`

Comment: Found a solution for my problem: `t('date.day_names').each_with_index.map  { |day, idx| [ day, idx ] }`

Comment: Looks like map.with_index is not available until Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `slice` the array, perform `map` on that set, then concatenate the rest of the array to the end of the returned array from `map`.

```
:participants => (item.item_participations[0..2].map { |item|
  {:item_image => item.user.profile_pic.url(:small)}
} + item.item_participations[3..-1])
```

Here's an example:

[image]